# Can I use jQuery UI Slide Effect without hiding the container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the slide effect from jQuery UI to slide a previously hidden container into the page. I need to slide a container that already exists over to make room for it. I'd like to use the same slide effect so they have the animation is the same, but I don't want to hide the other container at the end of the slide. Is this possible? Or is it possible to use `animate()` to achieve as smooth of a slide animation as I'm getting from slide?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `animate()`. The slide effect is in fact just that:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.effect-slide.js#L49